# How to switch between nested navigation graph in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

[image]

We have 2 separate graphs, and I want switch. i simply pass the welcome screen routh but that gave me an error

Error :- **Navigation destination that matches request NavDeepLinkRequest{ uri=android-app://androidx.navigation/WELCOME } cannot be found in the navigation graph NavGraph(0xf10c493b) route=home_graph startDestination={Destination(0x78c93dec) route=HOME}**

**NavGraphCode**

```
    @Composable
    fun RootNavigationGraph(
    navController: NavHostController,
    onBoardingPrefKeys: Boolean,
    IsLogin: Boolean
    ) {

    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        route = Graph.ROOT,
        startDestination = if (IsLogin) Graph.HOME else Graph.AUTHENTICATION
    ) {
        authNavGraph(navController = navController, onBoardingPrefKeys)
        composable(route = Graph.HOME) {
            HomeNav()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to navigate to a different nav graph you have to use the route of that graph and not the route of the `startDestination` in that graph. The `startDestination` will be loaded automatically once you navigate to the graph. Here is one example:

```kotlin
NavHost(
    navController = navController, 
    startDestination = "root"
) {
    composable("root") {  }
    navigation(
        route = "graph1",
        startDestination = "welcome"
    ) {
        composable("welcome") {  }
        composable("motivation") {  }
        composable("recommendation") {  }
    }
    navigation(
        route = "graph2",
        startDestination = "home"
    ) {
        composable("home") {  }
        composable("settings") {  }
        composable("about") {  }
    }
    
}
```

In order to navigate to `welcomeScreen` from any screen in `graph2`:

```kotlin
navController.navigate("graph1")
```

Comment: i am using "NavGraphBuilder" not simple navigation so we don't have navigation i have update my question please check and thanks for your response

Comment: @Atrick Faisal can you please share some resources your answer.